# Ways in which a knight can reach the diagonally opposite corner

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, chessboard

A knight is placed in a corner of an $8\times8$ chessboard. In how many different ways can this knight reach the diagonally opposite corner if it can not move on the same cell more than once?

Comment: Sounds like a computer programming problem to me.

Comment: @saulspatz - I agree with you, but this is not quite a dynamic program, so how would you approach this?

Comment: It's depth-first search.  Consider the cells as the vertices of a graph, where two vertices are adjacent if they are a knight's move apart.  Then you just want to write a backtrack program that counts the simple path from one corner to the opposite corner.

Comment: @antkam I think I spoke too soon.  I wrote a simple python script to do this by backtrack, and it happily computed the answer for a $5\times5$ chessboard, but I got tired of waiting for it to finish a $6\times6$ board.  Of course, I could write it in C instead, and I could cut out half the paths by symmetry, but I doubt that would get me to the $8\times8$ case.  Some better idea is needed.

Comment: I see that [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A212715/list) only lists it up to $6\times6$ so I think computing it for $8\times8$ would take major effort, if it were considered worthwhile.

Comment: [Here's](https://oeis.org/A001230/a001230.pdf) an interesting paper about counting knight's tours on an $8\times8$ chessboard.  I wonder if something similar might work, splitting the path along the diagonal instead of into top and bottom.